# How to change CSS of an exetrnal website in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to create a simple web wrapper for a messaging website as practice, and I've created this simple code to load that website into Electron. Now I want to change this site's CSS properties. Multiple sources, including the docs seem to imply that using `.webContents.insertCSS` is the easiest way to do this. But whenever I run my program, this doesn't work.

Here is the code that I have been working with:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, webContents} = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs'); 

const createWindow = () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadURL('https://messenger.com/login'); 

  win.webContents.insertCSS(`.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.g5gj957u.d2edcug0.hpfvmrgz.kud993qy.buofh1pr {
    margin-top: unset !important;
    }
    
    /* Scrollbar fixes. */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
        
    :root, .__fb-light-mode, .__fb-dark-mode{
        --messenger-card-background: #262626 !important;
        --surface-background: #353535 !important;
        --hosted-view-selected-state: #262626 !important;
    }
    
    .system-fonts--body{
      font-family: 'Geist Regular' !important;
    }
    
    .x1247r65{
        width: 0px !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
    
    .x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z
    .x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x2lah0s
    .x193iq5w.xurb0ha.x1sxyh0
    .xdj266r{
        display: none !important;
    
    }
    
    .x1heor9g.x1qlqyl8.x1pd3egz.x1a2a7pz{
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
    
    .xm81vs4,.xy80clv{
        border-right-width: 0px !important;
        border-left-width: 0px !important;
    }
    `);

}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: The example in the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsinsertcsscss-options) waits for the `did-finish-load` event before calling [insertCSS](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsinsertcsscss-options).  Might that be the problem?

Comment: @Yogi Thanks, it worked! I've seen some examples where they didn't use `did-finish-load`, so I thought that it did not matter.